# How can I make only one pricing card expand at a time when its button is clicked, instead of all cards expanding together in my code? using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Please help me open only one card when I click on it (all of them open at once now) using jQuery,
The question is related to multiple pricing cards, each with an associated button. When a user clicks on the button of a particular card, the goal is to ensure that only that specific card expands. should not open all cards.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var button = $this.find(".ha-unfold-btn");
      var unfoldData = $this.find(".ha-unfold-data");
      var unfoldRender = $this.find(".ha-unfold-data-render");
      // Get the original height of the ha-unfold-data element
      var originalHeight = unfoldData.outerHeight(true);

      // Function to fold
      function fold() {
        unfoldData.css("transition-duration", "500ms");
        height: unfoldRender.outerHeight(true) + "px";

        unfoldData.animate(
          {
            height: unfoldRender.outerHeight(true) + "px",
          },
          0
        );
        var timeOut = setTimeout(
          function () {
            unfoldData.css("height", originalHeight + "px");
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            button.find("span").text("Read More");
          } /* Specify the timeout duration in milliseconds */
        );
        unfoldData.removeClass("folded");
      }

      // Function to unfold

      function unfold() {
        unfoldData.css("transition-duration", "500ms");
        unfoldData.animate(
          {
            height: unfoldRender.outerHeight(true),
          },
          0
        );

        var timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
          unfoldData.css("height", "auto");
          clearTimeout(timeOut);
          button.find("span").text("Read Less");
        }, 500 /* Specify the timeout duration in milliseconds */);
        unfoldData.addClass("folded");
      }

      // Click event handler for the button
      button.click(function () {
        if (unfoldData.hasClass("folded")) {
          fold();
        } else {
          unfold();
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #99f443;
      font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    }
    .elementor-container {
      max-width: 1140px;
      display: flex;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    .elementor-row {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }

    .elementor-column {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      min-height: 1px;
      display: flex;
    }

    .elementor-column-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
    }
    .elementor-widget-wrap {
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-content: flex-start;
    }

    .elementor-element {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .elementor-column.elementor-col-33,
    .elementor-column[data-col="33"] {
      width: 33.333%;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-title {
      font-weight: 200;
    }

    .elementor-widget-container {
      position: relative;
      overflow: initial;
      padding: 48px 64px;
      border-radius: 0.5rem;
      background-color: #fff;
      /* box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 2.8rem rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.1); */
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .ha-unfold-widget-wrapper {
      align-items: center;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      background-color: #02010100;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-header,
    .ha-pricing-table-media {
      margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-price {
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-price-tag {
      margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
      color: #242424;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 60px;
      line-height: normal;
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-current-price,
    .ha-pricing-table-original-price {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-current-price .ha-pricing-table-currency {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 24px;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-price-text {
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-period {
      color: #8c8c8c;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-body {
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-features-title {
      font-family: "Nunito", Sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-features-title {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-features-list {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    li {
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    li {
      display: flex;
      align-items: baseline;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-features-list li > i,
    .ha-pricing-table-features-list li > svg {
      margin-right: 8px;
      min-width: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12.8px;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-feature-text {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .fa-check:before {
      content: "\f00c";
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-btn {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
      border-color: #d92e77;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #e2498a;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
      border-radius: 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-btn:hover {
      color: #d92e77;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-color: #d92e77;
    }
    .ha-pricing-table-badge {
      border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
      --pricing-table-badge-rotate: -90deg;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-badge--left {
      left: 0;
      transform-origin: left top;
      --pricing-table-badge-translate-x: -100%;
    }

    .ha-pricing-table-badge {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
      background-color: #e2498a;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 1;
      transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    }
    .ha-unfold-btn {
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 35px;
      border: solid 1px #dedede;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: #101010;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .ha-unfold-btn {
      padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
      border-color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #02010100;
    }
    .ha-unfold-widget-wrapper .ha-unfold-btn {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 35px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: #101010;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
      border-color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #02010100;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .ha-unfold-btn span {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .ha-unfold-btn:hover span {
      color: #99f443;
    }

    .ha-unfold-btn:hover {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .ha-unfold-widget-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .ha-unfold-data::after {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 11;
      height: 100%;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
      content: "";
    }
    .ha-unfold-data::after {
      height: 30%;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #99f44300 0%, #99f443 100%);
    }
    button:not(:disabled),
    [type="submit"]:not(:disabled),
    [type="button"]:not(:disabled) {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .ha-unfold-widget-wrapper .ha-unfold-data.folded {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .ha-unfold-widget-wrapper .ha-unfold-data.folded::after {
      display: none;
    }

    .ha-unfold-widget-wrapper .ha-unfold-data {
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-container">
  <div class="elementor-row">
    <div class="elementor-column">
      <div class="elementor-column-wrap">
        <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
          <section class="elementor-element">
            <div class="elementor-row">
              <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                  <div class="elementor-element">
                    <div class="ha-unfold-widget-wrapper">
                      <div class="ha-unfold-data">
                        <div class="ha-unfold-data-render">
                          <div class="elementor">
                            <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                              <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                <div class="elementor-element">
                                  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                    <div class="ha-pricing-table-header">
                                      <h2 class="ha-pricing-table-title">
                                        Starter
                                      </h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="ha-pricing-table-price">
                                      <div
                                        class="ha-pricing-table-price-tag"
                                      >
                                        <div
                                          class="ha-pricing-table-current-price"
                                        >
                                          <span
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-currency"
                                            >$</span
                                          ><span
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-price-text"
                                            >0</span
                                          >
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="ha-pricing-table-period">
                                        Per User / Month
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ha-pricing-table-body">
                                      <h4
                                        class="ha-pricing-table-features-title"
                                      >
                                        Features
                                      </h4>
                                      <ul
                                        class="ha-pricing-table-features-list"
                                      >
                                        <li class="">
                                          <i
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="fas fa-check"
                                          ></i>
                                          <div
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-feature-text"
                                          >
                                            Up to 1 User
                                          </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="">
                                          <i
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="fas fa-check"
                                          ></i>
                                          <div
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-feature-text"
                                          >
                                            500 Queries
                                          </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="">
                                          <i
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="fas fa-check"
                                          ></i>
                                          <div
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-feature-text"
                                          >
                                            Basic Statistics
                                          </div>
                                        </li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <a class="ha-pricing-table-btn" href="#"
                                      >DOWNLOAD FREE</a
                                    >
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <button class="ha-unfold-btn ha-unfold-icon-before">
                        <span>Read More</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                  <div class="elementor-element">
                    <div class="ha-unfold-widget-wrapper">
                      <div class="ha-unfold-data">
                        <div class="ha-unfold-data-render">
                          <div class="elementor">
                            <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                              <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                <div class="elementor-element">
                                  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                    <div class="ha-pricing-table-header">
                                      <h2 class="ha-pricing-table-title">
                                        Starter
                                      </h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="ha-pricing-table-price">
                                      <div
                                        class="ha-pricing-table-price-tag"
                                      >
                                        <div
                                          class="ha-pricing-table-current-price"
                                        >
                                          <span
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-currency"
                                            >$</span
                                          ><span
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-price-text"
                                            >0</span
                                          >
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="ha-pricing-table-period">
                                        Per User / Month
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ha-pricing-table-body">
                                      <h4
                                        class="ha-pricing-table-features-title"
                                      >
                                        Features
                                      </h4>
                                      <ul
                                        class="ha-pricing-table-features-list"
                                      >
                                        <li class="">
                                          <i
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="fas fa-check"
                                          ></i>
                                          <div
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-feature-text"
                                          >
                                            Up to 1 User
                                          </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="">
                                          <i
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="fas fa-check"
                                          ></i>
                                          <div
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-feature-text"
                                          >
                                            500 Queries
                                          </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="">
                                          <i
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="fas fa-check"
                                          ></i>
                                          <div
                                            class="ha-pricing-table-feature-text"
                                          >
                                            Basic Statistics
                                          </div>
                                        </li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <a class="ha-pricing-table-btn" href="#"
                                      >DOWNLOAD FREE</a
                                    >
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <button class="ha-unfold-btn ha-unfold-icon-before">
                        <span>Read More</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your click event is too vague, it is targeting all the items with that class. You will want to target a specific item, either the button or relative to the button that was clicked.

Comment: Also all your selectors are a bit ambiguous, or over reaching. How do you intend to target just the one section to unfold / fold?